# uItableviewcell to retrieve value dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i did an application which has imageview to capture image from camera and a button where button is clicked pickerView will appear by actionsheet and will choose type of image(jpg, png, bmp..), once select from picker, button title will change according to the pickerView result,

then i try to convert this to UITableView, which has 2 section ( 1 for image and 1 for select the type of the image,

now i'm having problem where i try to imageView into the cell but image was overlapping other cell, and once image capture from camera that imageView not updated but once scroll the table than only updated,

another problem is, once select 2nd section i able to call the pickerView to choose the image type as previously, but once select from pickerView i don't how to updated the cell.text

below is my code, can anyone help here or improve it,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1; 
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Image", @"");
            break;
        case 1:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Image type", @"");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
        {
            UIImageView *abc = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,100,100)];
            abc.image = imageView.image;
            [cell addSubview:abc];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"- Click here -";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"selected %d",indexPath.section);
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1) {
        NSLog(@"selected %d",indexPath.section);
        [self chooseType];
    }
}

- (void)chooseType{
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    NSArray *typeObject = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@".jpg",@".png",@".bmp",nil];

    self.pickerData = typeObject;

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(TypeDonePick)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
    [pickerView release];
    [actionSheet release];  
}


- (void)TypeDonePick
{
    NSInteger row = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    titleCause.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleCause.text = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@" %@ ",titleCause.text);
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

is it possible to change cell test from outside range UITable function

thanks

Comment: Please edit your post to put the code in code markup so that we can read it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the table doesn't know it needs to update the cells already visible. for a quick solution just add [tableView reloadData] after the user picks the image/image type, this will cause the table to recreate the cells and get the updated data from them.

If you want to update cells individually you can use [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] to get the cell you want to update. e.g.

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"updated text";
    // You might need to call the following function though I'm not sure
    // [cell.textLabel setNeedsDisplay];
```

If you want to update the image I suggest you add a tag to the imageView in the cell and then you'll be able to change it as follows:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];
imageView.image = updatedImage;
// Again you might need to tell the image to refresh it self
//[imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the LabelText of UITableViewCell at IndexPath, We can use the code below.
--> It works correctly!
(with this example, I change labelText at row 0 of tableView):

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
   cell.textLabel.text = @"updated text";
   // must to write line below to update labelText for row 0
   [tableView setNeedsDisplay];
```